# The first loading for a site was refused but freshing rendering the website properly. Django/Nginx/Gunicon/AWS Linux

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

The first loading for a site shows a connection refuse error.

```
This site can’t be reached
Xyz.com refused to connect.

Try:
    • Checking the connection
    • Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Then, when I refreshed the site, the site is up and running.

The tech stack for the site is on
Django
NginX
Gunicorn
AWS Ubuntu v18.

This is a bit unusal, where can I start off to check the connection?

Comment: Connection refused means there's nothing listening on that port. Look at `ss -ltpn` on the server before you make that first connection attempt, then again afterwards.

Comment: I found the problem but don't know what to do. When I check with mxtoolbox, the DNS lookup shows the correct IP addr but the DNS check shows a different IP addr. I changed the AWS hosted zone, but I have no clue about the IP addr in the DNS check.

Comment: You'd need to figure out the full DNS setup then. Did you buy the domain from Amazon or somewhere else?

Comment: I got if from other provider, not AWS.

Comment: When I checked the DNS with mxtoolbox, I've got SOA Serial Number Format is Invalid and the TTL is set 5 min. Does it help?

Comment: I got this Glue issue, saying GLUE was not sent for nameservers when checked with intodns.com..

Comment: Make sure the DNS records at the registrar provider are correctly pointing to the NS records that AWS shows in the hosted zone you've set up.

Comment: Solved. Just latency for the DNS record propagation. Many thanks.